# Symfony2 AvalancheImagineBundle/ Resizing images

Tags: css, image, symfony

how can i resize images using AvalancheImagineBundle without cropping images?

I have images which can be 100x50 or 50x100, then if i set thumbnail size to 50x50, i'll have only middle parts of these images (e.g from 25 to 75px of height)

```
    somewhat:
                type:    thumbnail
                options: { size: [50, 50], mode: outbound, allow_upscale: true }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Avalanche. It seems that was some sort of bug, or missing feature(correct me if im wrong). I would suggest you to use another bundle(also, Avalanche is no longer supported). 
Im using Liip in my projects: https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle 
It's based on Avalanche, so it's very familiar. In LiipImagine you can achieve what you want by using:

```
foo_filter:
    filters:
        thumbnail: { size: [50, 50], mode: inset }
```